# How is the sql query executed?

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a mysql query, and I want to understand how it gets executed.

```
SELECT COUNT(abet.id) AS count, 
       IF(abet.b_t <= 1396047600000 AND abet.e_t >= 1396047600000, '2014-03-29 00:00:00.0 CET',
       IF(abet.b_t <= 1396047600000 AND abet.e_t >= 1396047600000, '2014-03-29 01:00:00.0 CET',
       IF(abet.b_t <= 1396054800000 AND abet.e_t >= 1396054800000, '2014-03-29 02:00:00.0 CET','0'))) AS _index 
  FROM a_b_e_t AS abet 
 INNER JOIN a_s AS a 
    ON a.id = abet.a_s AND a.u IN (4, 3, 2, 1) 
 GROUP BY _index
```

What I think is when this gets executed in the server, the data set will be minimized by the WHERE clause, and on that minimized set of data, line by line the if conditions will be checked and the counter will be increased appropriately, so even if the second IF is valid for data in the line processed by the IF's above it it will not take that in consideration, right?

In other words one line in the data set which was considered by one if, will not be considered by another, is it so?

Comment: yes, you can think that in `select XXXX WHERE/JOIN/...` XXXX will be "executed" only once per data row.

Comment: Correct at a simplistic level, the where clause filters the row data, and the column data extraction is done on the chosen rows. The group by can then be applied and the result returned to the client. The dB will optimise those if statements but it will apply it to each row it receives. If you had aggregate functions they would apply to the whole data set and would be executed during the group by process

Comment: Okay, so is there some way in which I can execute the corresponding IF's in the rows on which the statement is already executed? One way that I can think of is to write seperate SELECT statements for each IF, but this will increase the time it takes to execute the query, another way might be using stored procs, of which I am not sure.